# how to initialize list of object pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

I want to build a linked list of pointers to objects, initializing it upon the definition, not to call `push_back()` several time it will be silly.

```
class Myclass {
    int x;
    string name;
    bool test;
    //whetever
public:
    Myclass();
    void inc_x();
    ~Myclass();
};
```

Main:

```
Myclass c1,c2,c3,c4;
list<Myclass*> mylist;
/*
    list<Myclass*> mylist={&c1,&c2}; compiler returns initialized by constructor not by {...}
*/
```

I tried to use `list<Myclass*>::list<Myclass*>` as for classes constructors form, but the complier returns that it requires template syntax.

What that means ?

How to initialize these kind of lists ?

How do I define the constructor rather than using the default one in this case?

Comment: Are you compiling with C++11 enabled?

Comment: no i didnt passed any arguments to the compiler

Comment: And you compile with what compiler?

Comment: @Glpa mingw32-g++ ,  gcc version 4.7.1 (tdm-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::initializer_list` and associated constructors are C++11 features, so must be enabled in your compiler. Have a look at the necessary documentation for your implementation for how to do this. In Clang or GCC you simply pass `-std=c++11` in your command-line invocation.

Comment: it works when i enable c++11 what about the other questions. is there any other methodes

Comment: Just using `push_front` repeatedly is probably your best bet if C++11 is not an option. Or you could initialize an array and use the list iterator range constructor.

Comment: you're right since my first objects arent allocated dynamically they will still there till the end, let say i have 20 object at the start i'd better put them in an array then using a loop add them to the linked list.